# This connection is not secure issue using Datalab on Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I successfully installed Datalab on Dataproc cluster and I followed the instructions in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-datalab), but when I try to use Datalab on Google Chrome, it shows "This connection is not secure".

When I try to modify the connection with notebook interface from `http://cluster-name-m:8080` to `https://cluster-name-m:8080`, the page didn't load.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue :'(

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [Cluster web interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces) documentation it has you:

1. Create an SSH tunnel
2. Setup a SOCKS proxy to use that tunnel
3. *Not* open random ports that have no security

I'd recommend you follow those directions, as they will provide access to the web interfaces but encrypt all traffic via the SSH tunnel. While the browser will indicate the connection does not use SSL, the mechanism that is moving data from your browser to the cluster (SSH) is encrypting all data in the tunnel. Unfortunately, the browser does not know about this so it creates a warning.